# Fridge turns on and off immediately

Tags: refrigerator

I have a fridge which cools well and seems to work normally most of the time. However, a few times per day the fridge switches on then switches off immediately.

> Is this something to be worried about? Is there a part that might be faulty?

Thanks in advance.

---

It is an old LG, similar to [this one](https://www.lg.com/us/refrigerators/lg-LTCS20220W-top-freezer-refrigerator#).

Comment: At a minimum, please [edit] your question to provide the brand & model # of the fridge in question. TBH, though, if it's keeping the interior at the proper temperature, I wouldn't think it's a major concern, though it's probably something to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

Most refrigerator/freezers have just one compressor.   The compressor runs to make the freezer cold.   When the refrigerator needs cooling, it takes air from the freezer.   You might be hearing a fan run to move cold air from the freezer to the refrigerator.

Comment: How long has the compressor been off before starting and shutting down? If less than 5 minutes it should be OK. The compressor needs to be off long enough for the high and low sides to equalize. This happens via the Capillary tube or whatever restrictor device is controlling the flow of refrigerant. I have a refrigerator freezer combo and it has coils and sensors on both freezer and refrigerator. Either will start the compressor but both have to be off for the compressor to stop.

Comment: It is not a fan run. The compressor turns on and after 1 second it turns off. This happens rarely, mostly when the door of the fridge is not open for long periods of time.